# FirebaseMessagingService onTaskRemoved() not called?

Tags: android, firebase, service, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is what the service in my manifest looks like at the moment,

```
<service
        android:stopWithTask="false"
        android:name=".FcmMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Yet, onTaskRemoved is still never called. I have a simple debug log which is supposed to print. I wish to have onTaskRemoved called to be able to remove notifications still being active when the app is swiped away from the active list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience has been that `FirebaseMessagingService` is very short-lived.  In the case of processing a received message, the service stops itself immediately after `onMessageReceived()` returns.  You can observe this by adding log output to `onDestroy()`.

So I think it's very unlikely that the service will ever be active when you swipe the app out of the task list. And if the service is not active, `onTaskRemoved()` is not called.